# PDFBox LayerUtility - Importing layers into existing PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox to manipulate PDF content. I have a big PDF file (say 500 pages). I also have a few other single page PDF files containing only a single image which are around 8-15kb per file at the max. What I need to do is to import these single page pdf's like an overlay onto certain pages of the big PDF file.

I have tried the LayerUtility of pdfbox where I've succeeded but it creates a very large sized file as the output. The source pdf is about 1MB before processing and when added with the smaller pdf files, the size goes upto 64MB. And sometimes I need to include two smaller PDF's onto the bigger one.

Is there a better way to do this or am I just doing this wrong? Posting code below trying to add two layers onto a single page:

```
...
...
..
overlayDoc[pCounter] = PDDocument.load("data\\" + overlay + ".pdf");
outputPage[pCounter] = (PDPage) overlayDoc[pCounter].getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);

LayerUtility lu = new LayerUtility( overlayDoc[pCounter] );
form[pCounter] = lu.importPageAsForm( bigPDFDoc, Integer.parseInt(pageNo)-1);
lu.appendFormAsLayer( outputPage[pCounter], form[pCounter], aTrans, "OVERLAY_"+pCounter );
outputDoc.addPage(outputPage[pCounter]);

mOverlayDoc[pCounter] = PDDocument.load("data\\" + overlay2 + ".pdf");                      
mOutputPage[pCounter] = (PDPage) mOverlayDoc[pCounter].getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);

LayerUtility lu2 = new LayerUtility( mOverlayDoc[pCounter] );
mForm[pCounter] = lu2.importPageAsForm(outputDoc, outputDoc.getNumberOfPages()-1);
lu.appendFormAsLayer( mOutputPage[pCounter], mForm[pCounter], aTrans, "OVERLAY_2"+pCounter );

outputDoc.removePage(outputPage[pCounter]);
outputDoc.addPage(mOutputPage[pCounter]);
...
...
```

Comment: Your code unfortunately is somewhat incomplete. It isn't apparent how you put other pages into the outputDoc. The `pCounter` variable seems to indicate that you do something similar to the above to every page, and in that case it is no surprise that the file size explodes because there are some deep copies involved that might just multiply shared resources.

Comment: Yes, pCounter is ideally the total no of pages. My only option was to use arrays because the above code runs in a loop and until outputDoc is saved, I need to store the data of every page somewhere separate or I run into COSVisitor exceptions. Is there a neater way of doing this? How can I limit the resouces? I cannot use the Overlay class since it does not have a facility to selectively overlay pages. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

With code like the following I don't see any unepected growth of size:

```
PDDocument bigDocument = PDDocument.load(BIG_SOURCE_FILE);
LayerUtility layerUtility = new LayerUtility(bigDocument);
List bigPages = bigDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

// import each page to superimpose only once
PDDocument firstSuperDocument = PDDocument.load(FIRST_SUPER_FILE);
PDXObjectForm firstForm = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(firstSuperDocument, 0);

PDDocument secondSuperDocument = PDDocument.load(SECOND_SUPER_FILE);
PDXObjectForm secondForm = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(secondSuperDocument, 0);

// These things can easily be done in a loop, too
AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform(); // Identity... your requirements may differ
layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer((PDPage) bigPages.get(0), firstForm, affineTransform, "Superimposed0");
layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer((PDPage) bigPages.get(1), secondForm, affineTransform, "Superimposed1");
layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer((PDPage) bigPages.get(2), firstForm, affineTransform, "Superimposed2");

bigDocument.save(BIG_TARGET_FILE);
```

As you see I *superimposed* the first page of `FIRST_SUPER_FILE` *on two pages* of the target file but I only *imported the page once*. Thus, also the resources of that imported page are imported only *once.*

This approach is open for loops, too, but **don't import the same page multiple times**! Instead import all required template pages once up front as forms and in the later loop reference those forms again and again.

(I hope this solves your issue. If not, supply more code and the sample PDFs to reproduce your issue.)

Comment: Appreciate your help MKL. Many thanks. I had already tried the above method (a little differently) but the problem here is that the form that your importing FIRST_SUPER_FILE, SECOND_SUPER_FILE is displayed over the original page and does not act as an overlay. The layer covers the content of the original page. That is the reason I need to take the FIRST_SUPER_FILE and then import the page from the BIG_SOURCE_FILE on top of it. Is there any other way to do this? Is there an index level that can be set for layers? If there is, this would make my life easier!

Comment: If you want to do it cleanly (i.e. without exploding file sizes), you'll have to improve the `LayerUtility` a bit. That utility class only knows how to **append** a form (`appendFormAsLayer`) which implies that that form is in the foreground. You'll need a method to **prepend** a form. As the `PDPageContentStream` constructor used in the existing method also only knows how to replace or to append, you will either have to improve that class, too, or create a helper method working analogously but prepending the new content stream instead of appending.