# Add page as layer from separate pdf(different page size) using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

How can I add a page from external pdf doc to destination pdf if pages have different sizes?
Here is what I'd like to accomplish:
[image]

I tried to use LayerUtility (like in this example [PDFBox LayerUtility - Importing layers into existing PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782153/pdfbox-layerutility-importing-layers-into-existing-pdf)), but once I import page from external pdf the process hangs:

```
PDDocument destinationPdfDoc = PDDocument.load(fileInputStream);
PDDocument externalPdf = PDDocument.load(EXTERNAL PDF);

List<PDPage> destinationPages = destinationPdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

LayerUtility layerUtility = new LayerUtility(destinationPdfDoc);

// process hangs here
PDXObjectForm firstForm = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(externalPdf, 0);

AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer(destinationPages.get(0), firstForm, affineTransform, "external page");


destinationPdfDoc.save(resultTempFile);

destinationPdfDoc.close();
externalPdf.close();
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert an PDPage within another PDPage with pdfbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256546/how-to-insert-an-pdpage-within-another-pdpage-with-pdfbox)

Comment: If your main focus is on the *hanging process* in your code, though, and not on *adding a page from external pdf doc to destination pdf if pages have different sizes* in general, more information is needed: I ran your code and it worked flawlessly for sample input documents I have here. Thus, the issue causing the hang depends on some additional factor. Probably your source documents are special and should be inspected.

Comment: Actually process doesn't hangs, the file is just not created at all.
If I cancel external page import, and just add this page to destination doc, everything works perfect: file is created, external page added as last page.

Comment: Here is the code that works if page is just added as next page: http://d.pr/n/11Dv1 - in case of import as form, the tmp file isn't created, no errors, nothing...

Comment: That looks like there is something special about your documents. Can you share them? Furthermore, please indicate the PDFBox version you are using. I'm testing with 1.8.8.

Comment: To simplify the test PDFs are created using Pages (Mac os x, print as pdf).

destination file (test-pdf2): http://d.pr/f/15wRf

external file (test-pdf): http://d.pr/f/1lqrz

code used for adding the page: http://d.pr/n/tUiI

result after 1st from 'test-pdf' added to 'test-pdf2': http://d.pr/f/18E64

code used for importing the page as form: http://d.pr/n/14j3L

version of pdfbox: 1.8.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70127/discussion-between-el-kopyto-and-mkl).

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with your files and your code (with the exception of the file paths), I even switched to PDFBox 1.8.2, but I could not reproduce an issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### PDFBox dependencies

**The main issue was that PDFBox has three core components and one required dependency. One core component was missing.**

In comments the OP clarified that

> Actually process doesn't hangs, the file is just not created at all.

As this sounds like there might have been an exception or error, trying to *envelope the code as a `try { ... } catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }` block* has been proposed in chat. And indeed,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fontbox/util/BoundingBox 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.LayerUtility.importPageAsForm(LayerUtility.java:203) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.LayerUtility.importPageAsForm(LayerUtility.java:135) 
    at ...
```

As it turned out, fontbox.jar was missing from the OP's setup.

The PDFBox version 1.8.x dependencies are described [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html). Especially there are the three core components **pdfbox**, **fontbox**, and **jempbox** all of which shall be present in the same version, and there is the required dependency **commons-logging**.

As soon as the missing component had been added, the sample worked properly.

### Positioning the imported page

**The imported page can be positioned on the target page by means of a translation in the `AffineTransform` parameter. This parameter also allows for other transformations, e.g. to scale, rotate, mirror, skew,...***

For the original sample files this PDF page

[image: Source page from test-pdf.pdf]

was added onto onto this page

[image]

which resulted in this page

[image: result of the OP's original code]

The OP then wondered

> how to position the imported layer

The parameter for that in the `layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer` call is the `AffineTransform affineTransform`. The OP used `new AffineTransform()` here which creates an identity matrix which in turn causes the source page to be added at the origin of coordinate system, in this case at the bottom.

By using a translation instead of the identity, e.g

```
PDRectangle destCrop = destinationPages.get(0).findCropBox();
PDRectangle sourceBox = firstForm.getBBox();
AffineTransform affineTransform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, destCrop.getUpperRightY() - sourceBox.getHeight());
```

one can position the source page elsewhere, e.g. at the top:

[image: result using the translation above]

### PDFBox LayerUtility's expectations

**Unfortunately it turns out that `layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer` appends the form to the page without resetting the graphics context.**

`layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer` uses this code to add an additional content stream:

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
        targetDoc, targetPage, true, !DEBUG);
```

Unfortunately a content stream generated by this constructor inherits the graphics state as is at the end of the existing content of the target page. This especially means that the user space coordinate system may not be in its default state anymore. Some software e.g. mirrors the coordinate system to have y coordinates increasing downwards.

If instead

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
        targetDoc, targetPage, true, !DEBUG, true);
```

had been used, the graphics state would have been reset to its default state and, therefore, be known.

By itself, therefore, this method is not usable in a controlled manner for arbitrary input.

Fortunately, though, the `LayerUtility` also has a method `wrapInSaveRestore(PDPage)` to overcome this weakness by manipulating the content of the given page to have the default graphics state at the end.

Thus, one should replace

```
layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer(destinationPages.get(0), firstForm, affineTransform, "external page");
```

by

```
PDPage destPage = destinationPages.get(0);
layerUtility.wrapInSaveRestore(destPage);
layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer(destPage, firstForm, affineTransform, "external page");
```

Comment: @mkl Please open an issue in JIRA for this. I usually gladly do this for you, but this time I'm not sure if I have fully understood the problem, so it's better you do it in your own words. (I think you want the option to reset the graphics context, but I wonder if the current situation is a feature, and not a fault).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Looking at its code I just found that the `LayerUtility` contains a method `wrapInSaveRestore` which, in case of unknown documents, you always should call before `importPageAsForm`. According to its JavaDocs `LayerUtility` simply has expectations only backed by "most document do wrap their content in save/restore state". Oh well, I'll edit my answer here.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Unfortunately that method `wrapInSaveRestore` is buggy itself, cf. [PDFBOX-2666](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2666). Oh well.