# Insert image as new layer to existing PDF using PdfBox 1.8.8

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox in my application to modify existing PDF files. 
I need to place a barcode to the first page of the PDF document.

So first i create new PDF file with inserted barcode:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap(document, awtImage);
PDPage pag = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(ximage.getWidth(), ximage.getHeight()));
document.addPage(pag);
PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, pag, false, false);
stream.drawXObject(ximage, 0, 0, ximage.getWidth(), ximage.getHeight());
stream.close();
```

Then i try to place it as new layer into existing PDF:

```
Point barlocation = new Point(0,0);
float Height = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
float Width = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
barlocation.setLocation(Width - pag.getMediaBox().getWidth(), Height - pag.getMediaBox().getHeight()); //I need to place it in the top right corner
LayerUtility layerUtility = new LayerUtility(doc);
List bigPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDXObjectForm firstForm = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(document, 0);
AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
affineTransform.translate(barlocation.x , barlocation.y);
layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer((PDPage) bigPages.get(0), firstForm, affineTransform, "barcode layer");
doc.save(path);
doc.close();
```

So it works well with PDF document ver 1.5 (created in MS Word 2010/2013). But it's not working correctly with PDF document version 1.6 position and size of the inserted layer are wrong (i can't post an image, so you can see the result here:http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=11_capture567.png

What should I change? Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Cf. section **PDFBox LayerUtility's expectations** at the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28303191/1729265): Apply `layerUtility.wrapInSaveRestore` to the target page before adding the layer.

Comment: Did you read the answer to your question on the PDFBox user mailing list?